# how to show a progress bar while deleting some content from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to delete large number of rows in a table for a specific user and I want user to know that his/her content is deleting. Only showing, it is deleting is easy but how to show that it is 'x' percent deleted or 100-x percent remaining dynamically?
Lets say using bootstrap progress bars

Comment: Is really the "show" is your problem, or how to detect where the "DELETE" query reached?

Comment: Dispatch the delete to MySQL in batches, using more restrictive `WHERE` criteria?

Comment: You can use long-polling methods using ajax. Find out the total amount of rows that are going to be deleted, then increment a number in a loop for each delete and calculate the percentage.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL can't predict the time a query will process or how much time is left on an ongoing process.

One thing you could do is delete the records in parts (i.e. 1000 records) and update the progressbar after each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Its easy. I am sorry I will only explain at this stage as I am a little occupied. But I can create the the code if you send me an email if you don't understand. Better yet, I will provide the code here so that other people my benefit.

1. The better way to do it is to use check boxes to select the records you want to delete. 
   on the list page create a div to display the percentage (  )When the records are selected and the delete button is clicked, as usual, there will be a PHP file that will process the deletion. process this using ajax so that the user should still see the list of records and the percentage div that is going to display the percentage.
2. In this PHP file (processing file), you need to get the total number of records you are deleting (count the selected check boxes) as well as count of total records in that table from the database. return these two values as JSON. this should be put in variables by the previous ajax call.
   In your index page (where the list of whatever you are deleting is), create two variables to keep the total records to delete and the total records in database then create a setInterval function to query the database of the remaining records using ajax. make sure the PHP file that is doing this request is echoing the number of records remaining in the database. (if the interval is like a second, this will query the database every second and return the total).

What all this means is, you have total of records to delete i.e 5500
the total of remaining records in the table you are deleting from 56000

Now in the setInterval function, calculate the percentage i.e.

var total_records = 5500;

var deleted_record = total_records still in database table - total records;

var percentage = deleted_records/total_records*100;

In within the setInterval function, add $("#percentage").html(percentage) where the percentage is the div that is going to display the percentage. This will display the result according to the interval set.

I hope this is easy enough to understand. They are many ways of doing this but to avoid confusion, this is the best I have got. I will post the code soon.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL do not predict how much time query will take.

However to reach your goal you can try to use triggers, but this will not guarantee to work very precise and you will need to make various formula for progress calculation yourself.

Another option would be deleting by known amount of records per query so your `php` script could calculate progress, but it is a big waste of resources.